# notify when Life of a git branch is greater than X days in Jenkins pipeline (declarative)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to achieve, posting a notification once the lifetime of a branch from Git is more than X days through jenkins declarative pipeline ... I have written some other emailext for post success and failures, but unable to do so the same for logics like if life of branch > X days, or time between previous two builds etc ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how Jenkins works. At least you can't really do such thing without running the build.